# Calling other scripts and using variables (Python)

Tags: python, scripting, module

i'm not sure how to go about this...

I want to use import to go to another script (Once it's called, the original script has finished) but I need the second script to print a variable from the original.

So, I can import the second script and use the prints fine, however if I try and import the original script so I can access the variable..

But if I do that, it just gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\luke\Desktop\k\startGame.py", line 2, in <module>
    import Storyline
  File "C:\Users\luke\Desktop\k\Storyline.py", line 1, in <module>
    import startGame
  File "C:\Users\luke\Desktop\k\startGame.py", line 56, in <module>
    Storyline.startGame1()


AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'startGame1'
```

I am trying to print this:

```
 print ("I see you have picked " + startGame.currentPokemon)
```

and I am calling it like this:

```
Storyline.startGame1()
```

and the currentPokemon is

```
currentPokemon = inputKK
```

(InputKK is an input of the starter pokemon)

Is there any way to do this? And yes, i'm making a pokemon game in Python, but it's a version that isn't using real pokemon names..

---

Storyline script:

```
import startGame

def startGame1():
    print ("Welcome to the H.Q of I.O.D")
    print ("I am Professor Steel.")
    print ("I see you have picked " + startGame.currentPokemon)
```

startGame script:

```
import Storyline
inputKK = input("Choose from, 'Craigby', 'Robinby' or 'KKby' ")


    if(inputKK == "Craigby"):
        print("Craigby is a electric type.")
        print("Craigby: Attack = 7, Defence = 3, Health = 6, Speed = 12")
    if(inputKK == "Robinby"):
        print("Robinby is a fire type.")
        print("Robinby: Attack = 6, Defence = 5, Health = 7, Speed = 7")
    if(inputKK == "KKby"):
        print("KKby is a water type.")
        print("KKby: Attack = 5, Defence = 8, Health = 11, Speed = 5")

    print("")

    os.system('cls')

currentPokemon = inputKK
counter = 0;
while(counter < 1):
    print("Welcome to pokeby.")
    print("Type S for [STORYLINE]")
    print("Type R for pokemon in the field [CURRENT IS GRASS] ")
    print("Type Q for [QUIT]")


    inputMainMenu = input("S/R/Q ...")

    if(inputMainMenu == "S"):
        os.system('cls')
        counter = counter + 2
        Storyline.startGame1()
    if(inputMainMenu == "R"):
        os.system('cls')
        counter = counter + 2
    if(inputMainMenu == "Q"):
        os.system('cls')
        inputExit = input("Are you sure you want to quit? Y/N ")
        if(inputExit == "Y" or inputExit == "y"):
            print("K")
        else:
            counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: You need a more descriptive title in the future.  Maybe an actual question, next time?

Comment: Please post the contents of `startGame.py`, and the list of functions in `Storyline.py`

Comment: Changed it something more appropriate, can't really describe it though..

Comment: This is not an appropriate use for `import`. You will need to rethink how you are structuring your script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't `import StartGame` in your `Storyline` script. Instead, just pass the desired value to your `StartGame1` function.

```
# Storyline.py
def startGame1(currentPokemon):
    print ("Welcome to the H.Q of I.O.D")
    print ("I am Professor Steel.")
    print ("I see you have picked ", currentPokemon)
```

Then in `startGame` you call `Storyline.startGame1(inputKK)` passing the name of the Pokemon.

BTW, it's a little confusing that your `startGame1` function isn't in the module `startGame`...

Comment: Yeah, the startGame1 was just a placeholder but I have re-structured the scripts. And thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to `import Storyline` into `startGame`, and also trying to `import startGame` into `Storyline`. You just can't do this kind of recursive import. While `import`ing `startGame`, `Storyline` is coming across your `Storyline.startGame1()` call before `startGame1()` has been defined, so you get the no attribute error.

You should restructure your files so that this becomes unnecessary.

Answer (score -1):

[*edit:* don't listen to me; it was late and I didn't think hard enough about what I was saying.]

You can't reference attributes or methods in a module like that. <s>What you need is to put your methods in a class.</s> Alternatively, <s>I think you could do `from Storyline import startGame1()`. But really,</s> use classes [if you want to]; [i think] they are good. [Python docs on classes here.](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html)

Comment: False. `import Storyline; Storyline.myFunction()` is the same as `from Storyline import myFunction; myFunction()`. Classes are useful, though not absolutely necessary

Comment: Furthermore, don't use classes when functions would do the job better.

Comment: thanks for the corrections. Wouldn't classes fit pretty well here though? startGame() is probably fine left as a function, but I can imagine each Storyline would be better treated as a class. I guess it all depends on the underlying code though. I suppose I probably overuse classes myself.